# Is it possible to update a Word document that has been set to read only without having to make a copy of it?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ms-word

I have to programmatically update 1000's of documents with new regulatory information (Covid-19 related), which are located in over 40,000 SharePoint document libraries.

Most of the documents can be updated OK, but on those that cannot, if I manually open the document I get this message:

"The author would like you to open this as read-only, unless you need to make changes."

Is there anyway to get round this using C#? Interop is not an option as the documents are updated on a server using SyncFusion software, so it is all back-end based.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance,

Jimmy

Comment: You should understand what SharePoint is, how it works first. You can't modify *any* document without downloading it first. Even if you run your code on the SharePoint server itself. Word documents use the docx format since 2006, which is a ZIP package containing XML. This means you don't really need Word to edit `docx` documents, you can open the file as a ZIP, or use the Open Office XML SDK to read and edit the documents

Comment: Which SharePoint version are you using? In all cases, whether you use SharePoint's Server-Side Object Model or the client side object model, you need to retrieve the document, open and modify it, then send it back. The APIs change from version to version though